# How can I make a python code with the csv module that change each row at respective iteration

Tags: python, csv

Suppose there is a csv file named 'example.csv':

```
a, b, c

a, b

a, b

a, b

a, b
```

I want to change all rows of this csv file to be `'a, b, c'` using a Python code with csv module, however suppose that this code is heavier than my computer's computing power so, perhaps, the program may be abruptly interrupted (Probably, the user stop the program). In this case, the progress of this csv must be saved. For example, if the code did two iterations and terminated, then the original 'example.csv' or copied version 'copied_example.csv' should be:

```
a, b, c

a, b, c

a, b, c

a, b

a, b
```

Comment: Question is not clear at all, starting with your CSV not being valid. A CSV has a fixed amount of columns, an empty value is indicated by `,,` or `,NULL,`.  Secondly, what does "change all rows of this csv file" mean? In the current state of your question I'd just output `a,b,c` to `copied_examples.csv` for every row in your original CSV... Update question, use better examples, define 'change'.

Comment: If the CSV is too heavy to handle, don't handle it. Just cut it up into multiple files first. Furthermore, check into the hints of @O'Niel given above.

Answer (score 0):

You could in theory loop through the csv and save changes in every loop. Instead of using a csv module, you could use normal open() and then write() in a loop.